# how I can bind a generated comboBox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I trying to bind a comboBox programmatically but my stuff doesn't work. Did I missed something?

In my MainWindow.cs a have;

```
_comboBox = new ComboBox();
_comboBox.Margin = new Thickness(5, 64, 0, 64);
_comboBox.Width = 40;
_comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
_comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";                 
_stackPanel.Children.Add(_comboBox);

Binding binding = new Binding("SetNumber_Collection");
binding.Source = ViewModel_SurveyWindow.SetNumber_Collection;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(_comboBox, ComboBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

In my ViewModel;

```
static SortedDictionary<int, string> _SetNumber_Collection = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
public static SortedDictionary<int, string> SetNumber_Collection
            {
                get
                {
                    return _SetNumber_Collection;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SetNumber_Collection != value)
                    {
                        _SetNumber_Collection = value;
                        OnPropertyChangedStatic("SetNumber_Collection");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistake in your code. Try this one

```cs
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
        private ComboBox _comboBox;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _comboBox = new ComboBox();
            _comboBox.Margin = new Thickness(5, 64, 0, 64);
            _comboBox.Width = 40;
            _comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
            _comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";                 
            _stackPanel.Children.Add(_comboBox);

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = ViewModel_SurveyWindow.SetNumber_Collection;
            //Set binding mode OnewayBind
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            //Should bind to ItemsSource
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` property to your `SetNumber_Collection` source property:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(_comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

You should also bind the `SelectedValue` property to another source property of type `int` that stores the currently selected value:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(_comboBox, ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty,
    new Binding("YourIntSourceProperty") { Source = ViewModel_SurveyWindow.SetNumber_Collection });
```